# Queue Simulation JAVA

Tags: java, queue, simulation

So I had to write this to simulate queues on two servers running the same operation, to compare if a shop needs to hire a second cashier depending on how efficient the simulation runs. Single queue with single server vs single queue with two servers. I write all my code in main rather than creating additional classes and calling/extending since JAVA is not my strong suite, it takes me a ton of time to come up with this stuff and I write very simple code so it gets really long as you can see. Are there any pointers that you folks can give me based on what you see, to help me streamline this? Within the methods, constructors or classes, groups of lines or code that can be reduced, be more efficient? This works with the desired results though. My apologies if this is not the right way to ask or not the right thing to ask, I will delete it. Thanks in advance.

```
public class SimulationProject1 {
private static int poissonDistr(double mean) {
    Random x = new Random();
    double J = Math.exp(-mean);
    int i = 0;
    double pD = 1.0;
    do {
        pD = pD * x.nextDouble();
        i++;
    } while (pD > J);
    return i - 1;
}

public class listNode {

    int data;
    listNode next;

    public listNode(int data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = null;
    }
}

private final listNode head;

public SimulationProject1() {
    this.head = null;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return (this.head == null);
}

public int getFirst() {
    return head.data;
}

public static class LinkedQueue extends SimulationProject1 {

    int size;
    int totalTime;

    private class Node {

        int items;
        int waitTime;
        int dead;
        Node next;

        public Node(int items) {
            this.items = items;
            waitTime = 0;
            dead = 0;
            size++;
            this.next = null;
        }

    }

    private Node head;

    public void enqueue(int items) {
        if (head == null) {
            head = new Node(items);
        } else {
            Node tmp = head;
            while (tmp.next != null) {
                tmp = tmp.next;
            }
            tmp.next = new Node(items);
        }
        this.size++;
    }

    public void dequeue() {
        if (this.head == null) {
            System.out.println("No customers in line");
        } else {
            this.head = head.next;
        }
        this.size--;
    }

    public void setWaitTime() {
        Node temp = head;
        while (temp != null) {
            temp.waitTime++;
            temp = temp.next;
        }
    }

    public void getWaitTime() {
        Node temp = head;
        if(temp != null){
        while (temp != null) {
            totalTime = temp.waitTime + totalTime;
            System.out.println("Total wait time: " + totalTime);
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        }else{
            System.out.println("Noone's waiting..");
        }
    }

    public void setTimeout() {
        Node temp = head;
        while (temp != null) {
            if (temp.waitTime >= 8) {
                temp.dead = 1;
                this.size--;
            } else if (temp.waitTime <= 8) {
                temp.waitTime++;
            }
            temp = temp.next;
        }
    }
}


public static void oneServer(LinkedQueue line, LinkedQueue cashier) {
    int cost = 0;
    int profit = 0;
    int timedOut = 0;
    int inLine = 0;
    double mean = 0.2;
    int [] customersServiced = new int[50];
    int [] customerWaitTime = new int[50];
    int [] customersInLine = new int[50];
    int [] profitData = new int[50];
    int [] costData = new int[50];


    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        cost = cost - 3;

        for (int j = 0; j < poissonDistr(mean); j++) {
            System.out.println("Customers Arriving");
            int items = (int) (Math.random() * 6 + 2);
            line.enqueue(items);

        }
        if (line.head != null && line.head.dead == 1) {
            timedOut++;
            line.dequeue();
            cost = cost - 10;
        }
        if (cashier.head == null && line.head != null && line.head.dead == 0) {
            System.out.println("Line Moving");
            cashier.head = line.head;
            line.head = line.head.next;
        }
        if (cashier.head != null && cashier.head.items > 0) {
            cashier.head.items--;
        } else if (cashier.head != null && cashier.head.items <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Available");
            profit++;
            cashier.head = null;
        }
        line.setWaitTime();
        line.setTimeout();
        System.out.println("Number currently in line: " + line.size);
        customersInLine[i] = line.size; 
        line.getWaitTime();
        customerWaitTime[i] = line.totalTime;
        System.out.println("Customers serviced: " + profit);
        customersServiced[i] = profit;
        profitData[i] = profit;
        costData[i] = cost;

    }
    while (line.head != null) {
        line.head = line.head.next;
        inLine++;
    }
    System.out.println("\n" + "-------------------------Stats-----------------------------" + "\n" + "Cost: " + 
            cost + "\nPer iteration: " + Arrays.toString(costData) + "\n");
    System.out.println("Profit: " + profit + "\nPer iteration: " + Arrays.toString(profitData) + "\n");
    System.out.println("In the line: " + inLine + "\nAccrued per iteration: " + Arrays.toString(customersInLine) + "\n");
    System.out.println("Timed out: " + timedOut + "\n");
    System.out.println("Total wait time: " + line.totalTime + "\nPer iteration: " + Arrays.toString(customerWaitTime) + "\n");
}

public static void twoServer(LinkedQueue line, LinkedQueue cashier, LinkedQueue cashier2) {
    int cost = 0;
    int profit = 0;
    int timedOut = 0;
    int inLine = 0;
    double mean = 0.2;
    int[] customersServiced = new int[50];
    int[] customerWaitTime = new int[50];
    int[] customersInLine = new int[50];
    int[] profitData = new int[50];
    int[] costData = new int[50];
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        cost = cost - 6;

        for (int j = 0; j < poissonDistr(mean); j++) {
            System.out.println("Customers Arriving");
            int items = (int) (Math.random() * 6 + 2);
            line.enqueue(items);

        }
        if (line.head != null && line.head.dead == 1) {
            timedOut++;
            line.dequeue();
            cost = cost - 10;
        }
        if (cashier.head == null && line.head != null && line.head.dead == 0) {
            System.out.println("Line Moving");
            cashier.head = line.head;
            line.head = line.head.next;
        }
        if (cashier2.head == null && line.head != null && line.head.dead == 0) {
            System.out.println("Line Moving");
            cashier2.head = line.head;
            line.head = line.head.next;
        }
        if (cashier.head != null && cashier.head.items > 0) {
            cashier.head.items--;
        } else if (cashier.head != null && cashier.head.items <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Available");
            profit++;
            cashier.head = null;
        }
        if (cashier2.head != null && cashier2.head.items > 0) {
            cashier2.head.items--;
        } else if (cashier2.head != null && cashier2.head.items <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Available");
            profit++;
            cashier2.head = null;
        }
        line.setWaitTime();
        line.setTimeout();
        System.out.println("Number currently in line: " + line.size);
        customersInLine[i] = line.size;
        line.getWaitTime();
        customerWaitTime[i] = line.totalTime;
        System.out.println("Customers serviced: " + profit);
        customersServiced[i] = profit;
        profitData[i] = profit;
        costData[i] = cost;

    }
    while (line.head != null) {
        line.head = line.head.next;
        inLine++;
    }
    System.out.println("\n" + "-------------------------Stats-----------------------------" + "\n" + 
            "Cost: " + cost + "\nPer iteration: " + Arrays.toString(costData) + "\n");
    System.out.println("Profit: " + profit + "\nPer iteration: " + Arrays.toString(profitData) + "\n");
    System.out.println("In the line: " + inLine + "\nAccrued per iteration: " + Arrays.toString(customersInLine) + "\n");
    System.out.println("Timed out: " + timedOut + "\n");
    System.out.println("Total wait time: " + line.totalTime + "\nPer iteration: " + Arrays.toString(customerWaitTime) + "\n");
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedQueue line = new LinkedQueue();
    LinkedQueue line2 = new LinkedQueue();
    LinkedQueue cashier = new LinkedQueue();
    LinkedQueue cashier2 = new LinkedQueue();
    oneServer(line, cashier);
    System.out.println("-------------------------Double Server------------------------------------");
    twoServer(line2, cashier, cashier2);
}
}
```

The output it too large to post, it has stuff like 
Numbers in line
Currently Waiting
Currently serviced
Cost
Loss
Profit
etc

Comment: I think you're looking for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @user7642744 : Probably identing could be better(spacing), but else, nice code ! One question : What are isEmpty and getFirst for ? Are you using them ? And why do you need private ? Does it make a difference if its public ? Why do you have some variables only declared as `int Size` but otherwise `private Node head` ? Does this matter to you ? You should know for yourself.

Comment: I will check that out, thank you @tnw

Comment: @user7185318 Thanks! That is the only way I know, I look at textbooks and pseudo code and check with tutors and come up with this stuff, and I was getting errors when using alternate declarations so this is the final error free product after almost two days of working. Yes all of that is being used.

Comment: For future reference, that amount of code is too much for SO,  for code reviews, yes but for help with an specific issue most people will ask you to reduce the lines

Comment: @user7642744 Youre welcome !